# A generic sql query to archive more than one table

Tags: sql-server, archive

How could we manage the archive process without writing separate stored procedures
in SQL Server 2000?

For example,

- There are two tables in current db-student and employee.
- The objective is to archive the data in these tables-
- `student` table - data older than 1 year
- `employee` table - data older than 2 years

The date field to be compared in the student table is field `CreatedDate` and that of employee
is `DOJ`

In addition, I have kept a configuration table with columns `ConfigtableName, ConfigColumnName ,  ConfigCutoffdate`.

a) How can I write a generic query so that it dynamically takes the table name as well as column 
name from the configuration table and insert the data to the archive dbs' tables?

Something like this....

```
INSERT INTO <ArchiveDb>.Dbo.<Table name obtained from config table>
    SELECT *
FROM <CurrentDb>.Dbo.<Table name obtained from config table>
WHERE   
       <ConfigColumnName  obtained from config table> < <Cutoffdate obtained from config table>
```

b) How to manage the identify field set option?

c) Is it possible if an error occur in the nth iteration, it could save the error detail to a log?

Comment: Normally, I'd say you're looking for a dynamic sql statement and probably a cursor that iterates through the config table and uses that plus one of the built-in meta tables (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS) to build out your insert statement(s) and then execute them. Lather, rinse, repeat (cursor) for all the tables in Config. However, for only 2 tables this is overkill. I'd just write the insert statements and hard code a lookup to the cutoff date for that table

Comment: SQL isn't about magic dynamic statements or reducing code, it is all about repetitive and redundant blocks of similar code based on rigid table definitions.  the farther you stray from this the more difficult complex and slow your code becomes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to construct such a dynamic query in a stored procedure is by using the [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933299%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) stored procedure. Read the documentation I linked. Is pretty straight forward.

I am not sure I understand what you mean "identity field set option", but if you are concerned about duplicate values in a column that should have unique values (PK), I'd recommend that you disable the unique indexes in the archive tables since they are for archiving. I don't assume there will be a major issue with duplicate values in an id column but most importantly, that situation should never arise anyway if the archiving tables are identical copies of the source tables.

If you want to catch errors in the nth iteration, you are going to have to enclose every iteration in a begin tran/commit tran block and check for errors. If there's one, you can log to any other table you choose; if not, then you commit the transaction. [Read this](http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_programming.html) for an example (scroll all the way down to the Transactions section).

Comment: If you're about to embark on the dynamic SQL path - you **must** read and digest [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) - absolutely essential reading....